# How to create superuser in yugabyte sql cloud cluster?

Tags: cloud, superuser, yugabytedb

I created a yugabyte cloud cluster (free one). But cannot get access to any **superuser** account. 
when i create cluster with default creadentials i.e. 'admin' as user and run

```
SELECT rolname, rolsuper, rolcanlogin FROM pg_roles;
```

it returns

```
           rolname        | rolsuper | rolcanlogin 
----------------------+----------+-------------
 postgres             | t        | t
 pg_monitor           | f        | f
 pg_read_all_settings | f        | f
 pg_read_all_stats    | f        | f
 pg_stat_scan_tables  | f        | f
 pg_signal_backend    | f        | f
 yb_extension         | f        | f
 yugabyte             | t        | t
 yb_superuser         | f        | f
 admin                | f        | t
(10 rows)
```

user 'admin' does not have superuser privileges

and if use 'postgres' as user and a password white creating cluster
and try to login it returns

```
Password for user postgres: 
ysqlsh: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "34.82.214.52", user "postgres", database "yugabyte", SSL off
```

But in case of YCQL I can get superuser access with both default 'admin' user on any custom user like 'postgres'

**How can I get super user access for YSQL ?**

Comment: Currently, it's not possible to have super user privileges. What's the reason that you need a super user?

Comment: Ttill now I don't have that necessity for su privileges. Actually we have superuser privileges in case of YCQL but not for YSQL so I was wondering of I did something wrong or so...

Comment: Is there su access for, if I upgrade my cluster ?

Comment: No, there is not. We'll help with any features that you'll need for super users access though (like creating extensions).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't, because it's a Yugabyte managed instance.

Please use the 'admin' user that is created by default, which gives most of the superuser capabilities.

For management of the database cluster, we have to prevent from performing activities that would compromise database security and get access to the environment.